# Paint Bucket in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I'm stuck on a problem and needed some help or guide for a possible solution.

Basically in my application there will be a map with several zones. 
The user can select any of these areas, at that time this area is filled with a color.

Imagine a map like this one, so i need to be able to change the color of only one country.
   [image]

Something like what happens in the books of paintings (https://itunes.apple.com/pt/app/colorfly-best-coloring-book/id1020187921?mt=8), or **Paint Bucket** command in the Photoshop .

Any idea how to get something like this on iOS ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're looking for an algorithm called "Flood fill" ie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: Maybe take a look here? https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill

Comment: thanks for the answer. please add a answer to the question so i can accept it.

Comment: @BenZotto imagine i need to change the color of a country automatically without the user touch. The only solution is to store the coordinates of that point and automaticly fill that country, or there is another, simpler, solution? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paint bucket technique you're looking for is a set of graphics algorithms usually called "[flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)". There are different approaches to the implementation depending on the circumstances and performance needs. (There is more at that wikipedia link.)

I have no experience with it, but here is a library from GitHub that purports to implement this for iOS given a UIImage object: https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill

Re: your question about doing this without user touch: yes, you'll want to keep a map of countries to (x,y) points so you can re-flood countries when required. That said, the intricacies of the county borders might make an algorithmic fill inexact without more careful normalization of the original source. If your overall map only contains a small set of possible states, there are other ways of achieving this goal, like keeping a complete set of possible images (created in ie Photoshop) and switching them out, or keeping a set of per-country "overlay" images that you swap in as needed. (But if the flood fill is accurate on that source image, and performant for your needs, then great.)